# How do I loop through regions using boto with python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

Python newbie..
Im trying to write a script that will connect to my AWS account using the keys I give it and then it will list what instances are in there and will do so by looping through each region. So I want it to connect and start in a region and list and then go to the next region and list and so on.
The code below works if I comment out the following lines but it only works for us-east-1 which is my default region in my AWS credentials file on my box. 
"regions = boto.ec2.regions()
for x in regions:"
If I uncomment those lines the script will return all of my instances once for each region. So I end up with a huge list of the same instances repeating over and over. What am I missing that will make this do what im wanting? Be easy, im pretty new to Python.
Thanks.

```
import boto.ec2
import os
import sys

ACCESS_KEY = raw_input("Enter your access key > ")
SECRET_KEY = raw_input("Enter your secret key > ")
if not ACCESS_KEY:
    sys.exit("ERROR: You did not enter anything for ACCESS KEY or SECRET KEY. Exiting...")

ec2_conn = boto.connect_ec2(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY)

regions = boto.ec2.regions()
for x in regions:
    reservations = ec2_conn.get_all_reservations()
    for r in reservations:
        for i in r.instances:
            print r.instances
            print 'Tags: ',i.tags['Name']
            print 'Public IP Address: ',i.ip_address
            print 'Private IP address: ',i.private_ip_address
            if (i.virtualization_type == 'hvm'):
                platform = 'Windows'
            else:
                platform = 'Linux'
                print 'Platform: ',platform
            print 'State: ',i.state
            print
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `boto.connect_ec2` into the first for loop, and pass it the region. Something like this:

```
import boto.ec2
import os
import sys

ACCESS_KEY = raw_input("Enter your access key > ")
SECRET_KEY = raw_input("Enter your secret key > ")
if not ACCESS_KEY:
    sys.exit("ERROR: You did not enter anything for ACCESS KEY or SECRET KEY. Exiting...")

regions = boto.ec2.regions()
for x in regions:
    ec2_conn = boto.connect_ec2(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, region=x)
    reservations = ec2_conn.get_all_reservations()
    for r in reservations:
        for i in r.instances:
            print r.instances
            print 'Tags: ',i.tags['Name']
            print 'Public IP Address: ',i.ip_address
            print 'Private IP address: ',i.private_ip_address
            if (i.virtualization_type == 'hvm'):
                platform = 'Windows'
            else:
                platform = 'Linux'
                print 'Platform: ',platform
            print 'State: ',i.state
            print
```

Comment: Thanks. That got me where I needed to be.

Comment: Well...sort of. It worked on one account but I think its because I only had 4 instances all in one region. When I ran the script on a different account it bombed and threw an error. It lists out everything in one region (us-east-1) and looks like when it tries to go to the next region it doesnt connect correctly. Do I need to reestablish the connection somewhere in there?
ERROR:
'ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:492: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed'

Comment: @TheRedSeth that's a separate issue. Your Boto certificates are out of date. I think you need to update the cacerts.txt in the boto folder.